# Insert javascript code into conference paper

Tags: javascript, formatting, ms-word

Can anyone reccommend the best way to put javascript code into a conference type paper. The paper is times new roman, size 10. In Microsoft Word 07 Ive tried Insert > Object > Object... > OpenDocument Text..But this method leaves the code to big for the columns..I reduced code size before pasting it to the MW object but when it pastes it reverts back to original larger font?? Can someone help me out here please?

Thanks

Comment: You are writing a paper for a conference in MS Word?

Answer (score 2):

Code needs to be displayed in a fixed size font (often Courier New) to look appropriate, not a proportional font.  You can paste the code into Word, then select the code and change the font and size to whatever looks good.  I often display code in Courier New / 9pt, but the desired size obviously depends a bit on the context in the document.

If you're a little more advanced in Word, you can create a style just for the code and then just apply the style to the block of code after pasting it in.

Comment: @Felix Kling yes..it is a college project report, and the template given was an MS word template on the IEEE site : http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/authors/authors_journals.html